# Meta-analysis with prognostic factors

Tags: multivariate-analysis, meta-analysis

I see that in prognostic factors study often there's reported a value of OR, RR associated with a best cutoff or a specified cutoff. Is it correct to meta-analyse this studies with a multivariate model meta-analysis (for example with mvmeta in R) and consider the cutoff and the OR or RR as different outcomes? How can one accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean each study reports the OR or RR for a number of cut-offs?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: I found this paper addressing my issue: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4973834/ using R and the mvmeta command, should I be able to perform a multivariate meta analysis using as outcome the hazard ratio and as two variables the cutpoint and the method used for the cutpoint?

Comment: You can also do it using the metafor package I would have thought.